# onload event callback problem for an iframe dom element in phonegap

Tags: iphone, cordova, dom, dom-events

Using this sample code:

```
var callBack  = function(evt){
    alert("Inside callback")
}

anIframe.addEventListener("load", callBack, false);
```

The above code doesn't seem to work in Phonegap-Iphone. The callback function is not called even if the iframe element has been loaded in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to the load iFrame http://denrobapps.com/2010/12/phonegap-and-iframes/ and then use postMessage to communicate between the iFrame and the PhoneGap window.

Or load the iFrame with this: [Allow external hosts in iframe on xcode 4.1 using phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489104/allow-external-hosts-in-iframe-on-xcode-4-1-using-phonegap)