# Allow external hosts in iframe on xcode 4.1 using phonegap

Tags: xcode, cordova

I'm trying to create an iPad/iPhone-app that displays an iFrame that links to an external site. (It's doesn't have to be in the App Store).

The problem is that when I load the app, it's takes me to Safari.

I know there was a setting in an earlier version of XCode, where you could specify which external hosts was allowed in the app. And that worked!

I can't seem to find the setting in 4.1...

Anybody know where I can locate it?

Cheers!

Comment: OK, I finally found it - by searching in the search-field in the project-search. It's in the left corner. 

I would post an answer with a screenshot, but SO won't let me:-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap reads a setting called 'ExternalHosts' - this one is used to whitelist allowed external domains.

Open phonegap.plist - the key should be there, if not, simply add it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But the problem is that I can't locate where I can set it in XCode 4.1

Comment: is this possible to edit using config.xml if we're using phonegapbuild?

Answer (score 2):

Changes to PhoneGap.plist or Cordova.plist

Change/add the following values in PhoneGap.plist or Cordova.plist file of your app.

MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: NO

AllowInlineMediaPlayback: YES

OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView: YES

and set ExternalHosts list as you require

here i do for showing gopoglemap in app

ExternalHosts

```
      *.google.com
      *.gstatic.com
```