# Show webpage with phonegap

Tags: cordova

Making an app with phonegap for the android platform.
I want to show a webpage from a certain tab from within the application.
An iFrame is not working, how could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to open other web pages from your site in the same WebView instead of opening them in a separate browser window (the default behavior)?

If so, in PhoneGap 1.1.0, you can override the onCreate() method of the DroidGap subclass in your project with the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setBooleanProperty("loadInWebView", true);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

If you need to load pages from more than one website or domain, you will need a different approach:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.addWhiteListEntry("yourdomainhere.com", true);
    super.addWhiteListEntry("anotherdomainhere.com", true);
    super.addWhiteListEntry("yetanotherdomainhere.com", true);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

To prevent an unsettling black screen between page loads, you can add the following code right after the super.onCreate() statement:

```
    super.setIntegerProperty("backgroundColor", Color.WHITE);
    super.setStringProperty("loadingPageDialog", "Loading page...");
```

Comment: Incidentally, this also works to permit IFRAMES to load pages from the whitelisted domains or websites.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a local html page with a redirect as such:

`<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://otherdomain.com">`

This works without whitelisting otherdomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this question [Allow external hosts in iframe on xcode 4.1 using phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489104/allow-external-hosts-in-iframe-on-xcode-4-1-using-phonegap)